# Android Styling: Setting border to 0sp does not remove border radius of Material Button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I am trying to style a button such that it does not have a border radius. I have tried setting the `radius` property to `0sp`, but that has not worked. Below is my code and a screenshot of the resulting button, which still has rounded corners.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="11sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:radius="0sp"
        android:text="#1 Lorem Ipsum"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the corner radius use the **`app:cornerRadius`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:cornerRadius="0dp"
    ../>
```

Outlined/Filled result:

[image]

About your layout, use `dp` instead of `sp` in these dimensions:

```
    android:layout_marginTop="11sp" //dp
    android:radius="0sp"  //dp and app:cornerRadius
```

and this style `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` shouldn't be used in `android:textAppearance`.